# Converting string object to hash object

Tags: ruby

How do i convert the below string object to hash object

```
 "---\nsources:\n  - https://github.sample.com/ios/cocoapod-release-specs.git\ntarget_definitions:\n  - abstract: true\n    children:\n      - dependencies:\n          - CommonUnitTestUtilLibrary:\n            - \"~> 6.0.0\"\n          - OCMock:\n            - \"~> 3.6.3\"\n        name: :KioskTests\n      - name: Kiosk\n    dependencies:\n      - AEonSecurity:\n        - \"~> 14.2\"\n      - CernPlatform:\n        - \"~> 12.0\"\n      - NewRelicAgent:\n        - \"~> 6.12\"\n      - OrionAppKit:\n        - \"~> 4.2\"\n    inhibit_warnings:\n      all: true\n    name: Pods\n    platform:\n      ios: '13.2'\n"
```

or

```
"---sources:-https://github.sample.com/ios/cocoapod-release-specs.gittarget_definitions:-abstract:truechildren:-dependencies:-CommonUnitTestUtilLibrary:-\"~>6.0.0\"-OCMock:-\"~>3.6.3\"name::KioskTests-name:Kioskdependencies:-AEonSecurity:-\"~>14.2\"-SampPlatform:-\"~>12.0\"-NewRelicAgent:-\"~>6.12\"-OrionAppKit:-\"~>4.2\"inhibit_warnings:all:truename:Podsplatform:ios:'13.2'"
```

Comment: What is the expected output? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? What did you try to get unstuck? [so] is not a "write-my-code-for-me"-service, you need to show your code and demonstrate your efforts.

Comment: I tried JSON.parse string.gsub('=>', ':') method. I want output in the below format.
`{"target_definitions"=>
  [{"name"=>"Pods",
    "abstract"=>true,
    "inhibit_warnings"=>{"all"=>true},
    "platform"=>{"ios"=>"13.2"},
    "children"=>
     [{"name"=>"CameraCapture",
       "dependencies"=>
        [{"OrionAppKit"=>["~> 4.4"]}, {"ImageCaptureLibrary"=>[{"git"=>"https://github.sam.com/doctimaging/imaecapture-ios-lib.git", "branch"=>"master"}]}, {"Peregrine"=>["6.0.0"]}, {"NewRelicAgent"=>["~> 6.10"]}]}]}],
 "sources"=>["https://github.cerner.com/ios/cocoapod-release-specs.git"]}`

Comment: The first one is YAML. The second one looks like YAML that has been irrevocably destroyed by removing all whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Your first string is YAML. Correctly formatted:

```rb
yaml = <<'EOF'
---
sources:
- https://github.sample.com/ios/cocoapod-release-specs.git
target_definitions:
- abstract: true
  children:
  - dependencies:
    - CommonUnitTestUtilLibrary:
      - "~> 6.0.0"
    - OCMock:
      - "~> 3.6.3"
    name: :KioskTests
  - name: Kiosk
  dependencies:
  - AEonSecurity:
    - "~> 14.2"
  - CernPlatform:
    - "~> 12.0"
  - NewRelicAgent:
    - "~> 6.12"
  - OrionAppKit:
    - "~> 4.2"
  inhibit_warnings:
    all: true
  name: Pods
  platform:
    ios: '13.2'
EOF
```

Otherwise, just assign the string you have to a variable like *yaml*. Then parse it into a hash:

```rb
require 'yaml'

hash = YAML.load(yaml)
pp hash
```

This will return a Ruby hash object:

```rb
{"sources"=>["https://github.sample.com/ios/cocoapod-release-specs.git"],
 "target_definitions"=>
  [{"abstract"=>true,
    "children"=>
     [{"dependencies"=>
        [{"CommonUnitTestUtilLibrary"=>["~> 6.0.0"]},
         {"OCMock"=>["~> 3.6.3"]}],
       "name"=>:KioskTests},
      {"name"=>"Kiosk"}],
    "dependencies"=>
     [{"AEonSecurity"=>["~> 14.2"]},
      {"CernPlatform"=>["~> 12.0"]},
      {"NewRelicAgent"=>["~> 6.12"]},
      {"OrionAppKit"=>["~> 4.2"]}],
    "inhibit_warnings"=>{"all"=>true},
    "name"=>"Pods",
    "platform"=>{"ios"=>"13.2"}}]}
```

The second string is probably unsalvageable unless you already know what the data is supposed to look like. Parsing a corrupted YAML file will yield corrupted results, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: I would suggest changing the heredocs `EOF` delimiters with `YAML`, following the [RuboCop style guide](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#heredoc-delimiters). Some IDEs will also adjust syntax highlighting based on the delimiter used.